# How to write effective readline code in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, readline

Trying to open and read one line at a time from a txt file, while collect the info and build up lists as I go.

So I have something looking like this:

```
name_list = []
rating_list = []
price_list = []
cuisine_list = []
end_list = []

filename = '/Users/anqixiao/Desktop/restaurant recommendation/restaurants_small.txt'
file = open(filename, 'r')
line = file.readline()

while line != '':
    name_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
    rating_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
    price_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
    cuisine_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
    end_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
file.close()
```

However, Python Shell has already stopped responding while I was manually entering the while loop. Can someone sheds some light on where I went wrong? I'd really appreciate it!

Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are reading the first line. If that line is not an empty string you enter the while loop, which then will execute forever, as you do no changes to "line". Just add another line "line = file.readline() inside the while loop.

Comment: `while line != '':` Will never fail if the `line` variable never changes inside the loop. You keep doing the same operations on the very first line forever and ever inside the loop. (When you use a `while` loop, make sure you're writing something inside the loop that causes the conditional to change)

Answer (score 0):

`line = file.readline()` will read a line from the txt file, but when you entered the while loop, **you are not reading the rest of the lines again** and **you are entering an endless loop.** That's why you are getting errors. **put the line = `file.readline()` inside the while loop**, after `while line != '':`

Answer (score 0):

An even saver approach would be:

```
name_list = []
rating_list = []
price_list = []
cuisine_list = []
end_list = []

filename = '/Users/anqixiao/Desktop/restaurant recommendation/restaurants_small.txt'

with open (filename, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()


for line in lines:
    if line != '':
        name_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
        rating_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
        price_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
        cuisine_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
        end_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
```

Using that you allow the file to have empty lines and just skip them. But as stated in my comment, your actual problem is a never ending while-loop.

Comment: what about using `file.read().splitlines()` instead? That way you don't need to strip `\n` 5 times.

Comment: @Rob Yeah I believe that is the correct syntax actually. I edited my original comment, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`line` refers to the first line of the document. Provided it is not an empty string, it will always be true, unless changed. To change it for each new line, you can simply put the `line = file.readline()` at the end of the while loop

Note that `file.readlines()` will read place every line in `file` into a list. `file.readlines().splitlines()` can do your stripping for you

Answer (score 0):

read file like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        #do something
```

if every line has each item like: "name,rating,price,cuisine,end",
you can use `split` to get items
if content line like: "name\n rating\n price\n cuisine\n end", this may be works

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        line = line.strip('\n')
        if idx % item_nums == 0:
            name_list.append(line)
        # other case
```